# Restructure and Condense JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

There are tons of post about formatting JSON, but I can't find one that fits my strange circumstance... here's my data source:

```
data = [{ "LoanOfficer": "Brett", "Year": 2014, "Month": 10, "FundedVolume": 304032.0000, "FundedUnits": 2.0000, "NewAppUnits": 2.0000, "RateLockUnits": 1.0000 },
    { "LoanOfficer": "Brett", "Year": 2014, "Month": 11, "FundedVolume": 179450.0000, "FundedUnits": 1.0000, "NewAppUnits": 1.0000, "RateLockUnits": 3.0000 },
    { "LoanOfficer": "Carlos", "Year": 2014, "Month": 10, "FundedVolume": 576615.0000, "FundedUnits": 3.0000, "NewAppUnits": 5.0000, "RateLockUnits": 3.0000 },
    { "LoanOfficer": "Carlos", "Year": 2014, "Month": 11, "FundedVolume": 341303.0000, "FundedUnits": 2.0000, "NewAppUnits": 5.0000, "RateLockUnits": null },
    { "LoanOfficer": "Carlos", "Year": 2014, "Month": 12, "FundedVolume": null, "FundedUnits": null, "NewAppUnits": null, "RateLockUnits": 1.0000 },
    { "LoanOfficer": "Elaine", "Year": 2014, "Month": 10, "FundedVolume": null, "FundedUnits": null, "NewAppUnits": 1.0000, "RateLockUnits": 1.0000 },
    { "LoanOfficer": "Elaine", "Year": 2014, "Month": 11, "FundedVolume": 348500.0000, "FundedUnits": 2.0000, "NewAppUnits": 1.0000, "RateLockUnits": 1.0000 },
    { "LoanOfficer": "Eric", "Year": 2014, "Month": 10, "FundedVolume": 768464.0000, "FundedUnits": 6.0000, "NewAppUnits": 5.0000, "RateLockUnits": 7.0000 }];
```

So, you can see I have multiple entries for the same `LoanOfficer`. Ideally, I would like to reformat this and sum it up so that there's only one entry per `LoanOfficer` and add the `FundedVolume` & `*Units` to this:

```
data = [{ "LoanOfficer": "Brett", "FundedVolume": 483482.0000, "FundedUnits": 3.0000, "NewAppUnits": 3.0000, "RateLockUnits": 4.0000 },
    { "LoanOfficer": "Carlos", "FundedVolume": 917918.0000, "FundedUnits": 5.0000, "NewAppUnits": 10.0000, "RateLockUnits": 4.0000 },
    { "LoanOfficer": "Elaine", "FundedVolume": 348500.0000, "FundedUnits": 2.0000, "NewAppUnits": 2.0000, "RateLockUnits": 2.0000 },
    { "LoanOfficer": "Eric", "FundedVolume": 768464.0000, "FundedUnits": 6.0000, "NewAppUnits": 5.0000, "RateLockUnits": 7.0000 }];
```

I tried this as a starting point, but i'm pretty sure this not the right route.

```
var UniqueD = {};
$.each(data, function () {
    i = 0;
    if (UniqueD[this.LoanOfficer])
        i = UniqueD[this.LoanOfficer];
    UniqueD[this.LoanOfficer] = i + this.NewAppUnits;
});
```

EDIT: I have a working function that gives me exactly what I want:

```
var rawdata = [...] // data source
var listOfOfficerStats = []; // new data
function Combine() {
    for (i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++)
    {
        var loExist = -1;
        for (j = 0; j < listOfOfficerStats.length; j++)
        {
            if (listOfOfficerStats[j].LoanOfficer == rawData[i].LoanOfficer)
                loExist = j;
        }

        if (loExist == -1)
        {
            //New
            var newObject = new Object();
            newObject.LoanOfficer = rawData[i].LoanOfficer;
            newObject.FundedVolume = rawData[i].FundedVolume;
            newObject.FundedUnits = rawData[i].FundedUnits;
            newObject.NewAppVolume = rawData[i].NewAppVolume;
            newObject.NewAppUnits = rawData[i].NewAppUnits;
            newObject.RateLockVolume = rawData[i].RateLockVolume;
            newObject.RateLockUnits = rawData[i].RateLockUnits;
            listOfOfficerStats.push(newObject);
        }
        else
        {
            //Add To Existing
            listOfOfficerStats[loExist].FundedVolume += rawData[i].FundedVolume;
            listOfOfficerStats[loExist].FundedUnits += rawData[i].FundedUnits;
            listOfOfficerStats[loExist].NewAppVolume += rawData[i].NewAppVolume;
            listOfOfficerStats[loExist].NewAppUnits += rawData[i].NewAppUnits;
            listOfOfficerStats[loExist].RateLockVolume += rawData[i].RateLockVolume;
            listOfOfficerStats[loExist].RateLockUnits += rawData[i].RateLockUnits;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to sum up each of the properties you're interested in totalling.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not called "reformatting" but "changing the structure entirely". "Reformatting" means changing whitespace and indentation that does not affect the _meaning_ of the data in any way. What you are trying to do affects the meaning a great deal.

Comment: Yes Pointy, that's what I'm trying to do. But I'm unsure of how to properly do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generic function:

```js
function sum(data, key, fields) {
    return data.reduce(function(out, rec) {
        var k = rec[key];
        out[k] = out[k] || {};
        fields.forEach(function(f) {
            out[k][f] = (out[k][f] || 0) + (rec[f] || 0);
        });
        return out;
    }, {})
}


// test


data = [{ "LoanOfficer": "Brett", "Year": 2014, "Month": 10, "FundedVolume": 304032.0000, "FundedUnits": 2.0000, "NewAppUnits": 2.0000, "RateLockUnits": 1.0000 },
    { "LoanOfficer": "Brett", "Year": 2014, "Month": 11, "FundedVolume": 179450.0000, "FundedUnits": 1.0000, "NewAppUnits": 1.0000, "RateLockUnits": 3.0000 },
    { "LoanOfficer": "Carlos", "Year": 2014, "Month": 10, "FundedVolume": 576615.0000, "FundedUnits": 3.0000, "NewAppUnits": 5.0000, "RateLockUnits": 3.0000 },
    { "LoanOfficer": "Carlos", "Year": 2014, "Month": 11, "FundedVolume": 341303.0000, "FundedUnits": 2.0000, "NewAppUnits": 5.0000, "RateLockUnits": null },
    { "LoanOfficer": "Carlos", "Year": 2014, "Month": 12, "FundedVolume": null, "FundedUnits": null, "NewAppUnits": null, "RateLockUnits": 1.0000 },
    { "LoanOfficer": "Elaine", "Year": 2014, "Month": 10, "FundedVolume": null, "FundedUnits": null, "NewAppUnits": 1.0000, "RateLockUnits": 1.0000 },
    { "LoanOfficer": "Elaine", "Year": 2014, "Month": 11, "FundedVolume": 348500.0000, "FundedUnits": 2.0000, "NewAppUnits": 1.0000, "RateLockUnits": 1.0000 },
    { "LoanOfficer": "Eric", "Year": 2014, "Month": 10, "FundedVolume": 768464.0000, "FundedUnits": 6.0000, "NewAppUnits": 5.0000, "RateLockUnits": 7.0000 }];

res = sum(data, "LoanOfficer", ["FundedVolume", "FundedUnits"]);
document.write(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a nice function, but I was unable to tweak it to my final version.

Comment: @Ponyboy: just add fields you want to sum up to the `fields` list: `sum(data, "LoanOfficer", ["FundedVolume", "FundedUnits", "NewAppUnits", etc])`

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a version](http://jsfiddle.net/k3g9nqka/2/) using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) and a chain of [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy), [map](https://lodash.com/docs#map) and [reduce](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce):

```
var data = [...]; //assuming your original data array here

function sum(total, n) {
    return total + n;
}

function sumProperty(data, prop) {
    return _.reduce(_.pluck(data, prop), sum);
}

var groups = _.groupBy(data, 'LoanOfficer');
var reduced = _.map(groups, function(group, groupName) {
    return {
        LoanOfficer: groupName,
        FundedVolume: sumProperty(group, 'FundedVolume'),
        NewAppUnits: sumProperty(group, 'NewAppUnits'),
        RateLockUnits: sumProperty(group, 'RateLockUnits')
    };
});
```

This is in no way intended to be optimal. Using some more specialized code you could improve this by only looping once over `data` to do the grouping *and* build all sums at the same time.